Reducing Build Time for React Native App on Windows Environment
I'm currently developing a React Native app using Expo on Windows, and I've encountered a significant bottleneck in the build process. When I submit the app for building, it takes approximately four hours to complete. I'm seeking advice on improving this build time, preferably by optimizing the local development environment.
Details:
Current Setup:
OS: Windows
Development Environment: Visual Studio Code
Framework: React Native with Expo
Issue:
Long build times, approximately four hours, when submitting the app for building.

I'm looking for suggestions or best practices to reduce the build time, particularly optimizing the local development environment.
Are there any specific tools, configurations, or techniques I should consider to expedite the build process?
Is there a recommended workflow or alternative approach to streamline the build process for React Native apps on Windows?


Do you use eas to build? Did you build local? What is your build command ? What are yours machine specs ?

i m using windows and i used  --eas build --platform android ,

Use the local flag --local to build on your machine  eas build --platform android --local. Maybe you need to run npx expo prebuild once first.
eas build --platform android will use free computing time if you are using a free plan.

you don't need to build all of ABIs (Application Binary Interfaces) if you're building locally and testing on emulator or a physical device. Add this flag
"--active-arch-only" after run command like "npx react-native run-android --active-arch-only".
